# Word mapped ContentControl returns messy data

Tags: c#, office-automation, word-automation

I'm writing a c# plugin that creates a ContentControl and maps it to an XML file.
When the XML have a node with something like "7, SOMESTREET" i get inside the ContentControl the text ",7SOMESTREET" ...
I live in Israel so my guess is that it must has something to do with locale.
I've tried everything i could think of (changing the XML encoding, changing the default formatting of the ContentControl, etc') - but still no luck.

Does anyone can think of something that may cause this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this:

> If you have more than one keyboard
>   (input locale) installed on your
>   system, when you start a blank
>   document--regardless of the template
>   in use--Word will automatically apply
>   direct formatting on the text matching
>   the currently active input locale,
>   thereby overriding the default setting
>   in the Language dialog box.

Here: http://word.tips.net/Pages/T001678_Changing_to_UK_English.html

Thats probably that..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the paragraph to Left-to-Right text order.